# Pyzbar recognizes EAN-13 barcode as PDF417?

Tags: python, opencv, barcode

I'm trying to build a realtime barcode reader using pyzbar. I have only EAN-13 barcodes and some of them are read properly but some are recognized as PDF417 and I get this message:
**WARNING: .\zbar\decoder\pdf417.c:89: : Assertion "g[0] >= 0 && g[1] >= 0 && g[2] >= 0" failed**
How to increase efficiency? Maybe there is another python library which I can use?

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

def decoder(image):
    imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(image,0)
    barcodes = decode(imgGray)

    for barcode in barcodes:
        (x, y, w, h) = barcode.rect

        cv2.rectangle(imgGray, (x-10, y-10),
                          (x + w+10, y + h+10), 
                          (255, 0, 0), 2)
              
        if barcode.data!="":
                
            print("Barcode: ", barcode.data)
            print(barcode.type)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    decoder(frame)
    cv2.imshow('Image', frame)
    code = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if code == ord('q'):
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have EAN-13, you could specify that so pyzbar would only check for EAN-13. You can specify the desired codes in a list to the parameter `symbols` when calling `decode(...)`.

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("testImage.png")
decode(image, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.ZBAR_EAN13])
```

(Code written from memory, sorry if eg the symbol isn't exactly right)

Another library to test would be [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). In my tests zxing was much slower than zbar but got better results.

Answer (score 0):

Let me modify the previous answer, since ZBarSymbol doesn`t have ZBAR_EAN13 attribute but EAN13 only. So the final code is:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode, ZBarSymbol
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("testImage.png")
decode(image, symbols=[ZBarSymbol.EAN13])
```